# problems with ajax when asigning the data gotten from database to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a controller where i managed to return a list of data from the database. This data is passed to a d3.js pie ([shown here](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/96447623ef4d342ee09b)). I get the data in the required format:

```
[{Nombre:'Investigador asociado C TC',freq:{NivelI:3,NivelII:0,NivelIII:0,SinSNI:7}},{Nombre:'Investigador emérito',freq:{NivelI:0,NivelII:0,NivelIII:3,SinSNI:2}},{Nombre:'Investigador titular A TC',freq:{NivelI:6,NivelII:0,NivelIII:1,SinSNI:3}},{Nombre:'Investigador titular B TC',freq:{NivelI:5,NivelII:10,NivelIII:3,SinSNI:1}},{Nombre:'Investigador titular C TC',freq:{NivelI:2,NivelII:16,NivelIII:20,SinSNI:3}},{Nombre:'Profesor titular B TC',freq:{NivelI:0,NivelII:0,NivelIII:0,SinSNI:1}}];
```

Part of the following sample data they use in this d3.js example is the following:

```
    [
      {State:'AL',freq:{low:4786, mid:1319, high:249}},
      {State:'AZ',freq:{low:1101, mid:412, high:674}}
    ]
```

Yes, as you can see, it does not look like a correct JSON format. Look at the *freq* variable, it has a subdivision string where it sums the *low*, *mid*, and *high* variables. So does this subdivision of the data make this array look incorrect to be a json format?

The strange thing is that, if i copy and paste that string of data inside the javascript file, the pie chart is displayed. However, if i get that same data via ajax, it does not work! I've been struggling with it for weeks. If it is the same data string, then why isn't the pie chart displayed???

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: '{{URL::route("query02")}}',
      type: 'GET',
      async: true,
      dataType: "json",//tried html, text, everything, ...
      success: function(datos,status, XHR) {
          console.log(datos);
          /*if i call datos and put the string here, It does work. For example:
          var datos=[{Nombre:'Investigador asociado C TC', ... NivelIII:0,SinSNI:1}}]; */
          /*Calling the pie chart function*/
          dashboard('#dashboard',datos);
      }
    });
});
```

I have tried everything i have read in other questions: stringify, jsonParse, html, text, etc!! :/

**Notes**: I have tried

```
dataType='json'
dataType="json"
dataType='html'
dataType='text'
```

What i have noticed is that, when dataType='json', the console.log(datos) does not display anything.

Moreover, the javascript gets an error:

> TypeError: fData.forEach is not a function

where:

```
fData.forEach(function(d){d.total=d.freq.NivelI+d.freq.NivelII+d.freq.NivelIII+d.freq.SinSNI;});
```

So it looks like the data received from ajax is not an array? or is there something more to make that string readable for the javascript??

What am i missing? How do i fix this?

**Semi fixed**
I have solved in a non-orthodox way:
I print the results to a .js file from the php controller by using:

```
file_put_contents('js/pathtomy/file.js',$contents);
```

where contents look like:

```
var freqData=[{Nombre:'Investigador asociado C TC',freq:{NivelI:3,NivelII:0,NivelIII:0,SinSNI:7}},{Nombre:'Investigador emérito',freq:{NivelI:0,NivelII:0,NivelIII:3,SinSNI:2}},{Nombre:'Investigador titular A TC',freq:{NivelI:6,NivelII:0,NivelIII:1,SinSNI:3}},{Nombre:'Investigador titular B TC',freq:{NivelI:5,NivelII:10,NivelIII:3,SinSNI:1}},{Nombre:'Investigador titular C TC',freq:{NivelI:2,NivelII:16,NivelIII:20,SinSNI:3}},{Nombre:'Profesor titular B TC',freq:{NivelI:0,NivelII:0,NivelIII:0,SinSNI:1}}];
        alert(freqData);
        dashboard('#dashboard',freqData);
```

In the view, i call that file like this:

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('js/pathtomy/file.js')}}"></script>
```

And it works fine. ☺

Yeah, i know this is redundant ... Nevertheless I wish i could have solved it properly. 
Noone could help :/ never mind. Moreover i got downvotes. *Buuu*.

Someday i will find the right solution the way i wanted it ... so bad.

Comment: Can you also show the output of your `console.log`? I would guess that your JSON is not valid.

Comment: I know the JSON does not look valid. The problem is that this d3.js example asks for a weird semi json look like format. This is part of the sample data they use: `[
{State:'AL',freq:{low:4786, mid:1319, high:249}}
,{State:'AZ',freq:{low:1101, mid:412, high:674}}]`. Another thing is that, if i put an alert showing the data type recieved, it says *object* when i write the data type inside the javascript file. If i get the **same** data sample from ajax, the alert says *string* and i get a type error where i understand it wants an array. So how do i pass this very special data format to array?

Comment: Do you get ajax response at all? You cannot use ajax cross-domain just like that, you have to use [other methods](http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/two-methods-handling-cross-domain-ajax-calls).

Comment: @skobaljic Yeah, i always get response from ajax and the same *string* of data but with the problem that it comes as a string and not as an object or the format the javascript wants. I programmed the controller to output the data in that specific format. If I copy that output to the javascript by myself (copy + paste) it does work! But not directly from ajax response, even if i get exactly the **same** data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sure you get a correct Javascript code, than you can simply use **[eval method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)**:

```
var response = "[{Nombre:'Investigador asociado C TC',freq:{NivelI:3,NivelII:0,NivelIII:0,SinSNI:7}},{Nombre:'Investigador emérito',freq:{NivelI:0,NivelII:0,NivelIII:3,SinSNI:2}},{Nombre:'Investigador titular A TC',freq:{NivelI:6,NivelII:0,NivelIII:1,SinSNI:3}},{Nombre:'Investigador titular B TC',freq:{NivelI:5,NivelII:10,NivelIII:3,SinSNI:1}},{Nombre:'Investigador titular C TC',freq:{NivelI:2,NivelII:16,NivelIII:20,SinSNI:3}},{Nombre:'Profesor titular B TC',freq:{NivelI:0,NivelII:0,NivelIII:0,SinSNI:1}}]";
eval('var freqData='+response);
console.log(freqData[0].Nombre);
```

Outputs:

```
Investigador asociado C TC
```